# how to check if variable value is one of the options in select2 when it opens?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

how to detect if my variable value does exist in one of the options inside the select2 ?
e.g I want to remove that option from the selections if it does exist once the select2 opens.

so far, I only have a condition to detect if the select2 is open, so how to check if my var does exist inside the options?

```
var myvariable = $('form#myform #toremove').val();
$('form#myform .select2').on('select2:open', function(e){
   //this part is wrong
   $('form#myform .select2 option').each(function(){
       if($(this).val() == myvariable){
           $(this).remove();
       }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Do you want the value removed completely from the `<select>` element, or you only want to hide it this specific time when the select2 is opened?

Comment: either way will do for as long as the user won't see that value among the list when it opened. do you have either techniques to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove it directly after opening

```
$('.select2 option[value="'+myvariable+'"]').remove()
```

Comment: daemn , that was a nice one liner . tnx :))))

Comment: @sasori, keep in mind that if your `myvariable` contains a quote (`"`) you will need to escape it (otherwise you will get a javascript error).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `<option>` elements when the menu is opened, and remove the relevant elements from the DOM:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#s1").select2();

  
  $("#s1").on('select2:opening', function (e, i) {
    $(this).find('option').each(function(i, e) {
      // You can check either the text or the value
      if ($(this).text() == 'Alabama' || $(this).val() == 'AL') {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select id="s1" multiple="multiple" width="100">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wait a sec... sorry ha, but the value of my variable is a key , hence I need to check if that key exist from that array in the select2 , not by text comparing